# nodejs y mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Amigos estoy asiendo un registro de clientes con documento entonces necesito validad que el documento no este registrado sierto tengo ya la parte de almacenar el cliente pero de hay a validar no he podido me pueden hechar una mano gracias.

```
router.post('/users/signup', async (req, res) => {
        //Validar si el email ya se encuentra registrado!!!
        const emailUser = await User.findOne({num: num});
            if(emailUser) {
            req.flash('error_msg', 'num ya se encuentra Registrado!!');
            res.redirect('/users');
        }

        const newUser = new User({name, email, password});
        newUser.password = await newUser.encryptPassword(password);
        await newUser.save();
        req.flash('success_msg', 'Usuario Registrado Exitosamente!');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: Hola Camilo, bienvenido a stackoverflow, creo que tu problema es que ¿estas validando un numero de telefono? lo digo por la condición que tienes al buscar un usuario  `{num: num}` no deberias buscar por email?

Comment: Sería de utilidad que pudieras subir tu modelo *User*. ¿Estás usando Mongoose?. Saludos

Comment: mira es el codigo real que tengo y me sale error router.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
    //Validacion de que numero del documento no se encuentre registrado
    const dcliente = new clients.fin({ident_numer: req.body.ident_numer});
        if(dcliente){
            req.flash('error_msg', `${ident_ncc} ya esta Registrado!!`);
            res.redirect('/users/signup');}
    //Almacena en la base de datos sin problema
    const cliente = new clients(req.body);
    await cliente.save();
    req.flash('success_msg', 'Cliente Registrado Exitosamente!');
    res.redirect('/');});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que estas usando `async` para obtener los datos, en tu primer error, veo que tienes `new clients.fin({ident_numer: req.body.ident_numer});` lo cual estas declarando de una manera incorrecta además que debe ser `find` y no `fin`, debería ser `const dclient = clients.findOne({ident_numer: req.body.ident_numer})`

Te propongo lo siguiente para buscar al usuario a quien quieres validar

```
    const dcliente = await clients.findOne({ident_numer: req.body.ident_numer});

    if(dcliente !== null){
       req.flash('error_msg', `${ident_ncc} ya esta Registrado!!`);//no se de donde sacas esta variable "ident_ncc"
       res.redirect('/users/signup');
       return;
    }

    //Almacena en la base de datos sin problema
    const cliente = new clients(req.body);
    await cliente.save();
    req.flash('success_msg', 'Cliente Registrado Exitosamente!');
    res.redirect('/');});
```

Comment: Amigo gracias esa me funciona prefecto amigo gracias amigo

Comment: @camilodiaz no de que, para eso es la comunidad para ayudarnos, si la respuesta te fue de utilidad puedes marcarla como aceptada.